# How to right align a div containing a form in another div?

Tags: html, css

This is my header.

[image]

My goal is to move the logout button to the far right, without loosing the ability of clicking on them.

Now, I have tried position relative and absolute and this moves the button to the right, but then the buttons are no longer clickable.

- adding the line position:relative; to #my-menus (makes the buttons unclickable)

I also tried adding a spacer, or making my logout button bigger but that did not work. the width was stuck to 125px whatever I did. (Those don't seem like valid solutions though...)

As is, the buttons are clickable.

What am I doing wrong? I am more interested in the why this is happening then how to fix it, since I can live with the current outcome. Also, if I'm totally using the wrong approach with all the divs and what not, let me know. I wish to learn.

Here are the html and css files:

---

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <div>
                <img src="styles\monkey-head-pic-hi.png" alt="">
                RotoMonkey
            </div>
            <div id="userGreeting">
                <p>Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("name")%>!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="my-menus">
            <div>
                <form method="get" action="homePageForm.jsp"> 
                    <input class="menuItem" type="submit" value="Home">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form method="get" action="loginForm.jsp"> 
                    <input class="menuItem" type="submit" value="Members"> 
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form method="get" action="loginForm.jsp">
                    <input class="menuItem" type="submit" value="Player Stats">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form method="get" action="loginForm.jsp">
                    <input class="menuItem" type="submit" value="Create League">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form method="get" action="loginForm.jsp">
                    <input class="menuItem" type="submit" value="Join league">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="logout">       
                <form method="get" action="loginForm.jsp">
                    <input class="menuItem" type="submit" value="Logout">
                </form>
            </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
#header
{
    width:100%;
}

#header div
{
    width:1000px;
}

#title
{ 
    background-color:white;
    height:75px;
    color:Green;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#title div
{ 
    float:left; 
    width:500px;
    height:75px;
}

img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin:5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#userGreeting
{
    position:relative;
    font-size: medium;  
}
#userGreeting p
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

#my-menus
{
    background-color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    z-index:-2;
}

#my-menus div
{
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
    border-right:thin solid white;
    width:125px;
}

/* #logout */
/* { */
/*  position:absolute; */
/*  right:0; */
/* } */

body {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
                inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}

input[type=submit] {
    border: green;
    background: transparent; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#64c8ef', endColorstr='#00a2e2',GradientType=0 );
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index:-10;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that is what you are trying to complete? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PUYFt/)

I just added:

```
#logout {
    float:right;
}
```

The problem is that all your `div` elements are `inline-block` and they keep stacking inline.
Your `position: relative` made buttons unclickable because `#my-menus` has `z-index: -2` and gets overlayed by `#header` element.

Comment: My god, it seems so simple now. Thanks for the explanation. Although, why are my buttons clickable in the first place? #my-menues is in header, so z-index is relative to #header?

Comment: That must also be why I need overflow:hiden for the green bar to show....Thanks a bunch!

Comment: According to documentation, `z-index` property only applies, when you explicitly assign `position` property. That is why its not getting overlayed without `position: relative`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in your css for right aligning a div

```
div{float:right;}
```